# merge data in a sharepoint2010 user profile property sync with sql using BCS

Tags: sharepoint-designer, user-profile, bcs, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

i have configured the user profile syncing with my custom SQL table.
i require 4 properties that are with 6 columns in the table

& the scenario is i have to concatenate the strings of the 3 columns of sql table in one property of user profile.

say sql structure is like

customer_id   number(10)      not null,
    customer_name   varchar2(50)    not null,
    address     varchar2(50),
    city    varchar2(50),
    state   varchar2(25),
    zip_code    varchar2(10),

i want to map address property of user profile with string = address + city +   state

please suggest any way to achieve this .

Answer (score 1):

This type of conditional behaviour is not suitable for a normal BCS connector. Instead create a .NET connectivity assembly that encapsulates your SQL calls, for example in LINQ, and create the logic in C#.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557349.aspx)

Comment: Adding on by normal BCS connector Ander's means Database connector

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it with BCS, but with PowerShell it would be pretty easy:

http://iedaddy.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-updating-user-profile-properties-with-powershell/

In the aboce example it uses a .csv file for data, but obviously other data connections could be utilized.